# react native fetch and axios is not sending request on android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, axios, fetch

i am using :

```
"react-native": "0.63.3",
"axios": "^0.21.0",
"react": "16.13.1",
```

and this is simple request to see if sending request is successful or not:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('log here fast');
    axios
      .get('http://api.github.com/users/hacktivist123/repos')
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('axios', response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('axios error', error);
      });

    fetch('http://api.github.com/users/hacktivist123/repos')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));

    console.log('log here slow');
  }, []);
```

and it's not even showing if request has been sent or not. i ran the project on a real device and it worked perfectly, i tried the solutions given in other questions but non of them worked.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.tasks">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      tools:targetApi="28" 
      >
```

even adding **network_security_config.xml** didn't help and didn't let to build the project with some errors.

Answer (score 0):

apparently it's a **bug in react-nativ**e, it's **open** on thier **github** **issues**, i tried with android api 21 and was sending the request but wasn't working with **api 29**.
[image]